# Vue router dynamic params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I cannot figure out the correct syntax for passing dynamic param data. I have tried a couple of variations, but I would assume I could inject someValue via:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'Foo', params:{ bar: ${someValue} } }">
```

However, I keep getting compiler errors.

Comment: i think you should do it like `<router-link :to="{ name: 'Foo', params:{ bar:someValue} }">` by assuming that `someValue` is a dynamic property

Comment: Yep, you're correct. Thought I already tried that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass any dynamic property via `router-link` params like :

```
 <router-link :to="{ name: 'Foo', params:{ bar:someValue} }">
```

`someValue` sould be a data object item or computed property, and if you want to pass a value returned with a method you could do it like :

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'Foo', params:{ bar:someMethod()} }">
```